# Java Excel I/0 issue

Tags: java, excel, io, apache-poi

To work with my project I needed to learn about the POI Api from apache. 
So I decided to create a small program that creates a spreadsheet and fills its cells with some values .

The problem is it doesn't do what it was supposed to and I'm pretty sure the logic is correct,  I doubt this has something to do with the way data are written to files but I can't fix it as I have a very poor experience dealing with I/O.

This is my code :

```
package excel;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;


public class Excel {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
         Sheet sheetTest = workbook.createSheet("TestPOI");

         Cell[] cell = new Cell[100];
         int k = 0, i=0, j=0;

         for( i=0; i<10; i++){
             for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                 System.out.println(k);
                 cell[k] = sheetTest.createRow(i).createCell(j);
                 cell[k].setCellValue(k);
                 k++;
             }
         }


    try{
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("MyWorkbook.xls");
    workbook.write(output);
    output.close();
    } //end try
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    } //end catch

    } // end of the main method
}
```

## Thanks in advance

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  What does it do instead?  In other words, what is specifically happening that you don't expect?

Comment: It is supposed to fill 100 cell ( 10 * 10 ) by some values .
Instead it only fills 10 cells ( the ones in the last row ) 
You can run the code and see for yourself .  Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems

1) You aren't separating rows and columns.  This means you are always using the same row/column

```
cell[k] = sheetTest.createRow(i).createCell(i);
```

2) You are creating the row each time.  You should only do this once per outer loop.

What you want:

```
for( i=0; i<10; i++){
     HSSFRow row = sheetTest.createRow(i);
     for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
         System.out.println(k);
         cell[k] =  row.createCell(j);
         cell[k].setCellValue(k);
         k++;
     }
 }
```

Note that I've changed the createCell() call to use "j" for the inner index.  And that I only create the row once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with this statement in your code:

```
         cell[k] = sheetTest.createRow(i).createCell(i);
```

i value will keep changing between 0-10. I think you need to use the following in terms of creating 100 rows:

```
             cell[k] = sheetTest.createRow(k).createCell(i);
```

Comment: It is actually `cell[k] = sheetTest.createRow(i).createCell(j);`

Comment: I have tried to convey that when you call createRow(), you are passing the value of i and the value of i will always be between 0-10 as you have a nested loop. If you pass k in createRow(), then you should be able to create 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected the code , now everything is working as it should .
Here's the correct code :

```
package excel;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
public class Excel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheetTest = workbook.createSheet("TestPOI2");

         // Creating an array of cells 

         Cell[] cell = new Cell[100];
         int k = 0, i=0, j=0;

         for( i=0; i<10; i++){
             Row row = sheetTest.createRow(i);
             for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                 cell[k] = row.createCell(j);
                 cell[k].setCellValue(k);
                 k++;
             }            
    try{
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("MyWorkbook.xls");
    workbook.write(output);
    output.close();
    } //end try
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    } //end catch

    } // end of the main method
}
```

## Thank you so much